# BigQuery - Count Unique Events Within 7 Days of Date

Tags: google-bigquery

[Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/g6qMb1Mnsrt3aGsbxGr5iQ/1)

What I hope to achieve is a query which will count how many unique campaigns exist within 7 days of the current campaign (including itself). In the fiddle I've manually added a column to show what the output should be, but how would I generate the column `Sent_Within_7_Days` using the `Send_Date` and `Campaign` columns?

I've tried using a mix of a window statement mixed and case statement but no dice.

Comment: I've been able to work out a way to get this answer, but is there a more efficent way of doing this rather than a type of self join? https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/g6qMb1Mnsrt3aGsbxGr5iQ/4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following. I can't say its more efficient (but is cleaner) (it will also depend on the table size), but for your purpose, there is no a much more efficient way.:

```sql
select Send_Date new_date, Campaign, Sent_Within_7_Days,
(select count(1) from Table1 where (send_date > date_sub(new_date,interval 7 day) 
and send_date <= new_date )) sw_7days from Table1;
```

The test [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ivcNZVLbd1qn2jBffAmn2t/0)